# Dividing a column into groups according to certain ranges

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula

(Not sure if I'm in the right community and please let me know if this question is more suitable in another one).

Anyway, I want to create a new column with group numbers according to specific ranges that will be looking in the column next to it. Considered vlookup and if-statements, which actually would do the job so I don't have to create something in VBA but it's not working:

```
=if(AC487>=600;3;if(600>AC487>=300;2;if(300>AC487>=60;1;if(60>AC487>=-60;0;if(-60>AC487>=-300;-1;if(-300>AC487>=-600;-2;if(-600>AC487;-3)))))))
```

```
Column AC Column AD (expected results)
2304      3
 760      3
 467      2
1500      3
-500     -2
  10      0
  25      0
-146     -1
-249     -1
 132      1
```

Comment: This question really needs sample data together with expected results.

Comment: Try replacing your semi-colons with commas. Also, break your double-condition checks up, so instead of -300>AC487>=-600, use AND(-300>AC487,AC487>=-600)

Comment: @Jeeped, I've insert samlple data and expected results.

Comment: @Gordon K, thank you for you answer. I've tried to do what you suggest (if I understood it correctly), but it is not working: =IF(AC487>=600,3 AND(600>AC487, AC487>=300,2 AND(300>AC487, AC487>=60,1 AND(60>AC487, AC487>=-60,0 AND(-60>AC487, AC487>=-300,-1 AND(-300>AC487, AC487>=-600,-2 AND(-600>AC487,-3)))))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a condition is tested it will proof as true or false. If true, then the appropriate result is returned. If false then the next condition is considered. There is no reason to reiterate the first condition (that has already proved false) in the second evaluation.

```
=IF(AC487>=600, 3,
     IF(AC487>=300, 2,
     IF(AC487>=60, 1,
     IF(AC487>=-60, 0,
     IF(AC487>=-300, -1,
     IF(AC487>=-600, -2, -3))))))
```

The second IF does not have to evaluate whether it is less than 600. We know it is less then 600 because the first IF failed and passed control over to the second.

**Alternate non-IF:**

```
=LOOKUP(AC487,
      {-1E+99,-600,-300,-60,60,300,600},
      {-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3})
```

(yes, you can have line feeds in a formula to help make sense of it.)

[image: LOOKUP and nested IF conditions]

Comment: that's how I initially started the if-statement but I must have forgotten the "-3" in the end. Anyways, thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

=IF(AC487>=600,3,IF(AND(600>AC487,AC487>=300),2,IF(AND(300>AC487,AC487>=60),1,IF(AND(60>AC487,AC487>=-60),0,IF(AND(-60>AC487,AC487>=-300),-1,IF(AND(-300>AC487,AC487>=-600),-2,-3))))))